# How to properly develop/debug Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webstorm

I just started developing my first Chrome extension.

Tutorials describe the process like this:

- put code in a folder
- load it into Chrome using Settings | Extensions
- run it & use Chrome devtools to set breakpoints.

However, this seems like an extremely tedious process. I use WebStorm and would much rather start the debugging session from there and also set breakpoints in WebStorm.

I am sure there must be an option and developers do not manually load the extension in chrome after every change.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients